# NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey - custom class

Tags: cocoa, nsmutabledictionary

I am using this in a UINavigation environment.
I have **customClassA**. It inherits **customClassB** and one of its object is a NSMutableDictionary.

I alloc and init customClassA in a viewController, then for adding data, I am pushing a new viewController into the stack. The addNewDataViewController sends the newly added data, a **customClassB** object back by its delegate. Everything works fine so far.

**customClassA** has to store the returned object (**customClassB**) into its NSMutableDictionary object with a key (an NSString created from NSDate).

I get "mutating method sent to immutable object" error and can't think of any solution.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

===========================

```
interface customClassA : NSObject
{
    NSDate date;
    NSArray *array; // will contain only NSString objects
}
// and the rest as customary
...

#import "customClassA.h"
interface customClassB : NSObject
{
    NSString *title;
    NSMutableDictionary *data; // will contain values of customClassA with keys of NSString
}
// and the rest as customary

...

#import "customClassB"
#interface firstViewController : UITableViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      self.customClassB_Object = [customClassB alloc] init];
      //  and the rest...
}

- (void)secondViewControllerDidSaveData:(customClassA *)aData
{
    [self.customClassB_Object.data setObject:aData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aData.date]];
    // update tableView
}
```

Comment: can you post some more code around the problem area and also how you are creating the NSMutableDictionary

Comment: I posted some codes. Hope that helps.

Comment: Where is customClassB_Object defined?

Comment: self.customClassB_Object is defined in the header file and alloc'd, init'd in viewDidLoad.

Comment: ya so you need to do self.customClassB_Object.data in the secondViewControllerDidSaveData

Comment: 1. I apologize. I made a mistake is the sample code. secondViewControllerDidSaveData returns customClassA object.   2. why do I need to pass the whole customClassB_object to secondViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are initializing the `NSMutableDictionary` with something like

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

It would appear that your `NSMutableDictionary` is getting created with an `NSDictionary` instance instead of a `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: Already did it. Didn't work. In fact, and gave it manually an object and a key, and when the addNewDataViewController poped, it was still holding that manually-fed object. But refuses to setObject:forKey !!!

Comment: You'll need to post some more code. Setting break points/doing logging around the problem area might help.

Answer (score 0):

Althoguh I added the following code to customClassB implementation, it still didn't work.

```
#implementation customClassB
- (id)init
{
      self = [super init];
      if (self)
          self.data = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      return self;
}
```

so I added two custom methods to my customClassB implementation, as well as in the header file:

```
- (void)appendData:(customClassA *)aData;
- (void)removeDataWithKey:(NSString *)aKey;
```

and instead of manipulating the data dicionary of customClassB in my viewController, I simply call that method and pass the data object to the class and it did the trick.